# How to find the parent element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the background color of the table cell when radio button inside the cell is clicked.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">  
      <input type="radio" value="foo" 
        onclick="this.parentElement.style.background-color='red';" />
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to get the parent element reference?

Comment: `parentElement` is a weird and totally pointless IE-only property. The spelling you are looking for is `parentNode`.

Comment: It would be more beneficial to post the real HTML output, not the Java-flavoured tags. `h:selectOneRadio` could quite easily get converted to some nested HTML tags and selecting the immediate parent  wouldn't work.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Using plain javascript:

```
element.parentNode
```

In jQuery:

```
element.parent()
```

Comment: I tried like this but its not working <h:selectOneRadio value="#{book.price}" onclick="this.parent().css('background', '#FEDA46');">

Comment: `this` in your case must be a jQuery element. try `$(this)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the change event of the select:

```
$('#my_select').change(function()
{
   $(this).parents('td').css('background', '#000000');
});
```